# Error installing/importing gdal (No module named 'osgeo')

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, gdal, osgeo

i've been stuck at this for hours and i can't get it to work.

I've fresh installed the newest version of anaconda3 from their website, but running "conda install -c conda-forge gdal' failed with "Solving environment: failed ..."

I uninstalled anaconda and installed an older version, but this time no errors and a bunch of packages got installed.

My anaconda3 folder has a bunch of gdal exe's, seemingly worked yes? But my python folder has no 'osgeo' folder, so trying to import in a python script gives me the error "No module named 'osgeo'"

Any advice would be hugely appreciated

Python version 3.7.3
conda version 4.9.0

Comment: I ran the gdal install command again without uninstalling everything and an osgeo folder is now present in my anaconda3/Lib/site-packages but still not in my python folder, so same missing module error. Whats the correct way to get it into the python folder? Surely a copy and paste isnt the right way right?

Comment: What OS are you working on? Please give some more info